# primefaces dialog onchange to load datatable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog, datatable

i am developing an application using jsf, primefaces and jpa. I'm facing one issue is that i'm using radio buttons and datatable in a dialog window. My condition is on selection radio button it invokes a method from the action and retrieves a list of data but i need to load the values in the datatable. But it is not loading the values in datatable

here is my xhtml code

```
<p:dialog header="RxnNo" widgetVar="dlg3" height="500" width="800">
     <p:selectOneRadio id="series" value="#{curation.series}">  
          <f:selectItem itemLabel="SGML" itemValue="1" />  
          <f:selectItem itemLabel="9000" itemValue="2" />  
          <f:selectItem itemLabel="8500" itemValue="3" />  
          <p:ajax listener="#{curation.getSeries9000}" update="seriesDataTable" />
      </p:selectOneRadio>
      <p:dataTable id="seriesDataTable" var="series" value="#{homePage.reactionsList}" widgetVar="seriesTable" scrollRows="20" scrollable="true" rowIndexVar="rowIndex">
             <p:column headerText="Id" filterBy="#{rowIndex+1}">                                    
                    <h:outputText value="#{rowIndex+1}" />
          </p:column>
       </p:dataTable> 
  </p:dialog>
```

here is my java code

```
public void getSeries9000() throws Exception {
        try {
            if (series.equals("2")) {
                series9000List = cationController.getAllSeries9000();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

can anyone help me to solve this problem.

Comment: How are you opening the dialog[dialogWidget.show()]. If you are using the commandButton please post that code also.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<p:dialog header="RxnNo" widgetVar="dlg3" height="500" width="800">
<h:panelGroup id="global">
     <p:selectOneRadio id="series" value="#{curation.series}">  
          <f:selectItem itemLabel="SGML" itemValue="1" />  
          <f:selectItem itemLabel="9000" itemValue="2" />  
          <f:selectItem itemLabel="8500" itemValue="3" />  
          <p:ajax listener="#{curation.getSeries9000}" update="global" />
      </p:selectOneRadio>
      <p:dataTable id="seriesDataTable" var="series" value="#{homePage.reactionsList}" widgetVar="seriesTable" scrollRows="20" scrollable="true" rowIndexVar="rowIndex">
             <p:column headerText="Id" filterBy="#{rowIndex+1}">                                    
                    <h:outputText value="#{rowIndex+1}" />
          </p:column>
       </p:dataTable> 
</h:panelGroup>
  </p:dialog>
```